# "Error: write ECONNABORTED" on deploying React App using Azure App Service extension

Tags: reactjs, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-active-directory, cloud

I am using Azure App Service Extension in Visual Studio Code. After logging into my Azure account from Visual Studio Code, I am trying to deploy my React app to Azure. After the deployment starts, I ran into the following error, and I have no idea what the cause is.

```
4:25:01 PM Demoapp: Creating zip package...
4:25:18 PM Demoapp: Starting deployment...
4:25:19 PM: Error: write ECONNABORTED
```

Comment: the error tells you failed to upload your files to `site/wwroot` under Kudu. In addition to deploy from VS Code you can also use other method upload files.  Be careful of the OS, it makes the deploy different.

Comment: Have you tried my solution yet? Is it work?

Comment: The problem was due to me being behind a corporate proxy. So I am not able to use FTP from this machine.

Comment: Is your error still exist? Is it possible that the corporate proxy caused this problem?

Answer (score 1):

An 'ECONNABORTED' error typically occurs when a multiple transfer fails, forcing the socket to be closed. The reason may be that tcp is automatically disconnected due to network congestion. You can try to reconnect or you can use other methods to deploy a react project such as [deploying with ftp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp).(any method of deploying is ok, all of them put your files under the site/wwwroot of Kudu. if one doesn't work you can try others.)

Comment: The problem was due to me being behind a corporate proxy. So I am not able to use FTP from this machine.